# Deleted logs are not rewritten to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I'm using `Logstash` to read log files and send to `Elasticsearch`. It works fine in a streaming mode, creating everyday a different index and writing logs in real time.

The problem is, yesterday at 3pm I occasionally deleted the index. It restored automatically and continued writing logs. However, I have lost the logs related to 12am - 3pm.

In order to rewrite the log from the beginning, I deleted the `sincedb` file, also added `ignore_older => 0` in the `Logstash` configuration. After that, I deleted the index again. But it continues streaming, ignoring old data.

My current configuration of logstash:

```
input {
      file {

        path => ["/someDirectory/Logs/20221220-00001.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        tags => ["prod"]
        ignore_older => 0
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        type => "cowrie"
      }        
}

filter {    
        grok {
           match => ["path", "/var/www/cap/cap-server/Logs/%{GREEDYDATA:index_name}" ]
        }
}

output {    
       elasticsearch {
          hosts => "IP:9200"
          user => "elastic"
          password => "xxxxxxxx"
          index => "logstash-log-%{index_name}"
       }
}
```

I would appreciate for any help.

I'm also attaching `Elasticsearch` configuration:

```
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
discovery.type: single-node
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Note, that after all configuration changes, `logstash` and `elasticsearch` have been **restared**.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but that wasn't specified in your question: did you restart Logstash after modifying the pipeline configuration?

Comment: In logstash `ignore_older => 0` tells a file input to ignore any files older than zero seconds old, so it usually ignores all files and processes nothing. (In filebeat it turns off age-based filtering.)